# Transient Fluid Dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Eventually, I would like to numerically simulate the transient compressible flow in an axial compressor during start-up.
However, I know that this is a very challenging undertaking (to say the least).
Nonetheless I would like to ask if there are recommendations for background literature, simple models, examples, frankly anything that can get me started.
I recognize that is a potentially board question, but my "google-mojo" has left me on this one and the [related Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_flow) is very brief.

Comment: You might try looking at the engine simulation literature in combustion. I don't know any specific papers off the top of my head, but I know that the simulation package KIVA (in its various incarnations) has been used to simulate combustion during an engine cycle, and I assume that a moving piston simulation is the type of problem you're looking at solving. However, I wouldn't actually use KIVA, because the code is messy.

Comment: @ Schorsch, try searching Masters or Doctoral theses on this topic on Google.

Comment: @Subodh : Thanks. But as I said *my "google-mojo" has left me on this question*, hence I ask here. Can you offer any **non-obvious** keywords?

Comment: @GeoffOxberry : Thanks. I'll take a look at KIVA.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already found an answer yet... Try looking here for some articles here: 
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=unsteady+compressible+turbomachinery+openfoam

OpenFoam is probably the most popular open source code that could possibly be used to solve this problem.  This presentation may be of help: http://www.personal.psu.edu/dab143/OFW6/Presentations/alex_wouden_slides.pdf

There is a full list of available CFD codes, just google "free cfd codes list".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will definitely take a look at OpenFoam. My question may have been unclear, but the focus should have been on **transient** not *free cfd codes*. I'll see what OpenFoam has to offer in terms of *transient* computations.